# Why NDEigensystem does not show the minimum eigenvalue?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, matrix, numerics, finite-element-method

I would like to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions using `NDEigensystem`. The following system is considered: $$H[u(\rho,z)]=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta u(\rho,z)+Vu(\rho,z)$$ where $V=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}}-\frac{3e^{-3\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}}+e^{-7\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}}}{\sqrt{\rho^2+z^2}}$

Below are two codes, the first code **(1)** is to find eigenvalues and eigenfunctions using `NDEigensystem`. The second code **(2)** is finding eigenvalues and eigenfunctions by matrix method. In this case I can estimate the value of the minimum eigenvalue using minimization, because this approach uses parameters dependent basis functions.

**(1)**
With the use of `NDEigensystem`, the minimum eigenvalue is -0.329556. 
In the both codes I renamed $\rho≡r$

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

rmax = 30;
zmax = 30;

V[r_, z_] := -(1/
     Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]) - (3 (E^(-3 Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]) + 
       E^(-7 Sqrt[r^2 + z^2])))/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]

H = Simplify[-1/2*
     Laplacian[u[r, z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] + 
    V[r, z]*u[r, z]];

{vals, funs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{H + u[r, z]}, 
   u[r, z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 100, 
   Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", \
{"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}}, 
     "Eigensystem" -> {"Arnoldi", "MaxIterations" -> 10000}}];

Sort[vals - 1]

(*{-0.329556, -0.129353, -0.0996647, -0.0570438, -0.0555859, \
-0.0478791, -0.0338522, -0.0332227, -0.0321545, -0.0306885, \
-0.0228879, -0.0221102, -0.0195824, -0.0178194, -0.0134078, \
-0.0131479, -0.00638181, -0.00461305, -0.00226629, 0.000615921, \
0.00246069, 0.00713658, 0.0121566, 0.0150791, 0.0164991, 0.0195553, \
0.0209365, 0.0263934, 0.0285584, 0.0335753, 0.0355955, 0.0369134, \
0.0418356, 0.045981, 0.0508021, 0.051836, 0.0567986, 0.0568928, \
0.059726, 0.0648629, 0.0671563, 0.0732491, 0.0753428, 0.0755007, \
0.0794506, 0.0828858, 0.0836577, 0.0935551, 0.0980983, 0.0986071, \
0.0988963, 0.103791, 0.105917, 0.110704, 0.116505, 0.117394, 0.12031, \
0.12446, 0.125365, 0.129507, 0.13085, 0.13276, 0.137021, 0.144945, \
0.146664, 0.148891, 0.15654, 0.159095, 0.160471, 0.162447, 0.168228, \
0.170975, 0.173943, 0.176716, 0.179559, 0.183812, 0.184116, 0.190538, \
0.192467, 0.194558, 0.197421, 0.199266, 0.207298, 0.207793, 0.213011, \
0.216477, 0.21986, 0.220111, 0.229101, 0.231261, 0.235627, 0.240813, \
0.241493, 0.24344, 0.247215, 0.24818, 0.250832, 0.255031, 0.258738, \
0.264149}*)
```

**(2)**
Now let's move on to the matrix method and consider Gaussian functions as basis functions.

The basis set: $\psi_{ij}=e^{-b_{j} z^2}e^{-a_{i} \rho^2}$ , where $a_{i}=a_1 * qa^{i-1}$, $i=1, 2 ,3,..., i_{max}$ and $b_{j}=b_1 * qb^{j-1}$, $j=1, 2 ,3,..., j_{max}$ are geometrical progressions ($a_1$, $b_1$, $qa$, $qb$ are parameters).

In order to estimate the minimum eigenvalue, it is sufficient to take a small basis set. The basis set of just two functions (imax=1, jmax=2) already gives a minimum eigenvalue much lower (vals min=-4.00166) than that obtained using the `NDEigensystem` (vals min=-0.329556).

Why are the values so different? It seems to me that `NDEigensystem` doesn't output the smallest eigenvalue, but starts from the second one.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]


(*basis set*)

imax = 1; jmax = 2;

geoseq[init_, r_, n_] := init*r^(n - 1);


Psi[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, r_, z_, i_, j_] := 
  Exp[-geoseq[b1, qb, j]*z^2]*Exp[-geoseq[a1, qa, i]*r^2];


(*\[Minus]1/2 \[CapitalDelta]*)

Kk[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = 
 Integrate[
  FullSimplify[
    Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2]*
     Laplacian[Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1], {r, \[Theta], z}, 
      "Cylindrical"]] r, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, 
   Infinity}, 
  Assumptions -> {a1 > 0, b1 > 0, qa > 0, qb > 0, i1 > 0, j1 > 0, 
    i2 > 0, j2 > 0}]
-((Sqrt[\[Pi]] (b1 qa (qa^i1 + qa^i2) qb^(j1 + j2) + 
    2 a1 qa^(i1 + i2) qb (qb^j1 + qb^j2)))/(
 a1 (qa^i1 + qa^i2)^2 Sqrt[b1 qb] (qb^j1 + qb^j2)^(3/2)))

Kx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, 
  c_List?MatrixQ] := -1/2 2 Pi Sum[
   c[[i1, j1]] c[[i2, j2]] Kk[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, j2], {i1, 1,
     imax}, {i2, 1, imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}]


(*V(r,z)*)

V[r_, z_] := -(1/
      Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]) - (3 (E^(-7 Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]) + 
        E^(-3 Sqrt[r^2 + z^2])))/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2];

VP[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] := 
  NIntegrate[
   Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2]*V[r, z]*
    Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1]*r, {r, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}];

Vx[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c_List?MatrixQ] := 
  2 Pi Sum[c[[i1, j1]] c[[i2, j2]] VP[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, 
      j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];


int[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, i1_, j1_, i2_, j2_] = 
  Integrate[
   Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i2, j2]*
    Psi[a1, b1, qa, qb, r, z, i1, j1] r, {r, 
    0, \[Infinity]}, {z, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
   Assumptions -> {a1 > 0, b1 > 0, qa > 0, qb > 0, i1 > 0, j1 > 0, 
     i2 > 0, j2 > 0}];

norm[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, c_List?MatrixQ] := 
  2 Pi Sum[c[[i1, j1]] c[[i2, j2]] int[a1, b1, qa, qb, i1, j1, i2, 
      j2], {i1, 1, imax}, {i2, 1, imax}, {j1, 1, jmax}, {j2, 1, jmax}];


H[a1_, b1_, qa_, qb_, 
   c_List?MatrixQ] := (Kx[a1, b1, qa, qb, c] + Vx[a1, b1, qa, qb, c])/
   norm[a1, b1, qa, qb, c];


(*finding the minimum eigenvalue*)

FindMinimum[{valsmin = 
   H[a1, b1, qa, 
    qb, {{c11, c12}}], (0.1 < a1 < 10) && (0.1 < b1 < 10) && (1.1 < 
     qa < 10) && (1.1 < qb < 10) && (0.1 < c11 < 10) && (0.1 < c12 < 
     10)}, {{a1, 1.22}, {b1, 0.44}, {qa, 1.40}, {qb, 1.81}, {c11, 
   1}, {c12, 1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 3, PrecisionGoal -> 3, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> {Print["a1=", a1, "   b1=", b1, "   qa=", qa, 
    "   с=", {{c11, c12}}, "   vals min=", valsmin]}]

(*{-4.00166, {a1 -> 8.21271, b1 -> 4.56641, qa -> 3.79284, 
  qb -> 5.76842, c11 -> 5.0677, c12 -> 3.29988}}*)
```

Comment: Using `Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"Direct"}}` yields a lowest eigenvalue of `-5.61306`, so it may be that the problem lies in some details of the Arnoldi solver.

Comment: @Michael Seifert, thanks! Could you please write the expression in full. Because if I write like this: `{vals, funs} = 
 NDEigensystem[{H + u[r, z]}, u[r, z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax},
   100, Method -> \
{"Eigensystem" -> {"Direct"}}]` this gives the following values `-0.222278 + 0. I, -0.125203 + 0. I, -0.0790437 + 0. I, -0.0555639 + 
 0. I, -0.0555584 + 0. I ...`

Comment: @MamMam Please, check, how your code works for Coulomb potential  `V[r_, z_] := -(1/
     Sqrt[r^2 + z^2])`.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks! I have tested both codes with Сoulomb potential. Both approaches give acceptable minimum energy values. The `NDEigensystem` gives these values `-0.503414, -0.125427, -0.125, -0.0557499, -0.05558,` and the matrix method minimization gives `{-0.433221, {a1 -> 0.292474, b1 -> 0.177462, qa -> 4.3895, 
  qb -> 5.01775, c11 -> 4.77766, c12 -> 2.81548}}` which is a good result for two basis functions

Comment: @MamMam Thank you. This is good. On the next step please use `V[r_, z_] := -(1/
     Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]) - eps (3 (E^(-3 Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]) + 
       E^(-7 Sqrt[r^2 + z^2])))/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]` and plot Min[vals] for `{eps,0,1/3,1/30}`. Let compare it with the same plot for your code with `a, b`.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thanks a lot! If I understand correctly, I need to plot the dependencies of the minimum eigenvalue on the eps for both codes. For the **(1)** code I have the following sequence: `minvals = {{0, -0.5034141789280298}, {1/30, -0.527434002050279}, {1/3, -1.051471745263509}}`. For the **(2)** code:  `minvals = {{0, -0.433221}, {1/30, -0.4445268902298323}, {1/3, -0.6242457056290964}}`. It seems that the behavior is similar in both cases, with an increase in the eps value, the minvals decreases

Comment: @MamMam Perfect! On the next step please compute first and second code on `{eps, 0, 2/3, 1/30}`.  You will see that  `NDEigensystem` can't compute ground state at `eps>=7/15`. Instead it compute second state.

Comment: @Alex Trounev, I got values for the `eps=2/3`. In the case of calculation **(1)**, the minimum eigenvalue `minvals=-0.2397973108946687` does not fit the general dependence, because it is much higher than the minimum eigenvalue for the `eps=1/3` (`eps=1/3`, `minvals=-1.051471745263509`). In the case of the **(2)** calculation, the minimal eigenvalue behaves as expected and has a smaller value (`eps=2/3`, `minvals=-1.410134668620058`) than for smaller `eps`

Comment: @Alex Trounev, why can't `NDEigensystem` get the minimum eigenvalue for some `eps` values, and how to make`NDeigensystem` calculate all eigenvalues?

Comment: @MamMam To compute up to `eps=0.7` use code `UT[r_] := -(1/r) - eps (3 (E^(-3 r) + E^(-7 r)))/r; RR = Simplify[-1/2*Laplacian[u[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] + UT[r]*u[r]];  sol[x_] := 
 NDEigensystem[{RR /. eps -> x}, u[r], {r, 0, 12}, 10, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> .001}}}]; lst = 
 Table[{x, Min[sol[x][[1]]]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/30}]`

Comment: @Alex Trounev, thank you very much! It is got the following values `{{0, -0.5}, {1/30, -0.522351}, {1/15, -0.547853}, {1/10, -0.577058},... {2/3, -2.65009}, {7/10, -2.94042}, {11/15, -0.230558}, {23/30, -0.236531}, {4/5, -0.242555}, ...`. At the `eps=11/15`, the function again begins to return the second eigenvalues. It is not very clear what to do if I want to get the minimum eigenvalue for the certain `eps` value? The behavior seems to change as the `r` changes. As the `r` decreases, the minimum eigenvalue can be reached by increasing the `eps` value

Comment: @MamMam:  I think I also modified the code to only return something like 3–5 eigenvalues rather than 100.  I'm not at a computer with Mathematica right now, so I can't test that out;  but maybe try asking for a smaller number of eigenvalues with `"Eigensystem" -> {"Direct"}` and see what happens?

Comment: @Michael Seifert, thanks! On my computer, which has 32 gigabytes of RAM, Matheamtica fills all the memory during calculations and gives the next error: The current computation was aborted because there was insufficient \
memory available to complete the computation. This happens when running `{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{H + u[r, z]}, u[r, z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 3, Method -> {"SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.05}}},  "Eigensystem" -> {"Direct"}}];`

Comment: @Michael Seifert, when using only this option `{"Eigensystem" -> {"Direct"}}` `NDEigensystem` produces the following values: `{-0.222278 + 0. I, -0.125203 + 0. I, -0.0790437 + 0. I}`. Here I have used this construction: `{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{H + u[r, z]}, u[r, z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 3, Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> {"Direct"}}];` And in both cases `NDEigensystem` does not output the value `-5.61306`. That's why I asked about the full expression )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this case can be used second code from my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/753794/why-does-the-minimum-energy-of-motion-in-a-coulomb-field-differ-from-the-theoret) for the Slater type orbitals. First we define potential in the form

```
VP1[r_] := -1/r - eps (3 (E^(-3 r) + E^(-7 r)))/r;
```

where `0<=eps<=1` is parameter. Code is given by

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
nmax = 5; var[n_] := Table[c[n, l], {l, nmax}];
Psi[r_, n_] := r^(n - 1) Exp[-r];
(*kinetic energy*)
Kk[r_, n1_, n2_] := 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, n2]*
    Laplacian[Psi[r, n1], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]];
Kx[n_] := -1/2 Sum[
    c[n, l1] c[n, l2] Integrate[
      Kk[r, l1, l2]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}], {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}];
(*potential energy*)

VP1[r_] := -1/r - eps (3 (E^(-3 r) + E^(-7 r)))/r;
Px1[n1_, n2_] := 
  Integrate[Psi[r, n2]*VP1[r]*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
Px[n_] := Sum[c[n, l1] c[n, l2] Px1[l1, l2], {l1, nmax}, {l2, nmax}];


norm[n_] = {Sum[
     c[n, l1] c[n, l2] NIntegrate[
       Psi[r, l1] Psi[r, l2] r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}], {l1, 
      nmax}, {l2, nmax}] == 1};

sol[n_, x_] := 
  NMinimize[{Kx[n] + Px[n] /. eps -> x, norm[n]}, var[n]];
```

With this code we compute data

```
lst5 = Table[{x, sol[1, x][[1]]}, {x, 0, 1, .1}]
```

Data `lst5` we can compare with 2D model same as above

```
rmax = 19;
zmax = 6;

V[r_, z_] := -(1/Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]) - 
  eps 3 (E^(-3 Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]) + E^(-7 Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]))/
    Sqrt[r^2 + z^2]

H = Simplify[-1/2*
     Laplacian[u[r, z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] + 
    V[r, z]*u[r, z]];



sol2[x_] := 
  NDEigensystem[{H /. eps -> x}, 
   u[r, z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 60];

lst2 = Table[{x, sol2[x][[1]] // Min}, {x, 0, 1, 1/30}]
```

Note, that to compute the ground state we can transform 2D model in 1D model as follows

```
UT[r_] := -(1/r) - eps (3 (E^(-3 r) + E^(-7 r)))/r;
RR = Simplify[-1/2*
     Laplacian[u[r], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"] + UT[r]*u[r]];

sol1[x_] := 
  NDEigensystem[{RR /. eps -> x}, u[r], {r, 0, 12}, 10, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> .001}}}];   
lst1 = Table[{x, Min[Sort[sol1[x][[1]]]]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/30}]
```

Finally we compare ground state computed with `NMinimize` (solid line) and with `NDEigensystem` in 1D (red points), and in 2D (blue 0)

```
Show[ListLinePlot[lst5, Frame -> True], 
 ListPlot[lst1, PlotStyle -> Red], 
 ListPlot[lst2, PlotStyle -> Blue, PlotMarkers -> "0"]]
```

[image: Figure 1]

From this picture we see similar jump from the ground state to the first excited state in 1D and 2D model as well. The reason is that Arnoldi method used as default is unstable. We can try option `Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}`. But with this method we compute ground state with lower accuracy,

```
UT[r_] := -(1/r) - 
  eps (3 (E^(-3 r) + E^(-7 r)))/r; oper = -1/2/r^2 D[r^2 D[u[r], r], 
    r] + UT[r] u[r];

sol[x_] := 
 NDEigenvalues[{oper /. eps -> x}, u[r], {r, 0, 12}, 20, 
  Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}]; lstd = 
 Table[{x, Min[sol[x]]}, {x, 0, 1, 1/30}]
```

Visualization `lstd`(black dashed line) with data shown above
[image: Figure 2]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed description! Could you please write down the expression that uses this method `Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}` in full. Because when I write like this `{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[{H + u[r, z]}, u[r, z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 100, Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}]`, Mathematica outputs the following eigenvalues `{-0.222278 + 0. I, -0.125203 + 0. I, -0.0790437 + 0. I, -0.0555639 + 0. I, -0.0555584 + 0. I, -0.0413612 + 0. I`. That is, the ground state is also skipped

Comment: @MamMam Please, see update to my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much! But if I understand correctly, there is a typo in your expression `-1/2/r^2 D[r^2 D[u[r], r], r]` because this expression is the Laplacian in polar coordinates, but in my expression, the eigenvalues of which I would like to get, there is also a fraction 1/2 in front of the Laplasian. Now if we put this missing fraction in the expression `oper` (`oper = -1/(2*2)/r^2 D[r^2 D[u[r], r], r] + UT[r] u[r]`), then the graph of the minimum eigenvalues will again undergo the jump `{{0, -1.11662},..., {2/5, -6.95461}, {13/30, -0.537784},..., {1, -1.03206}}`

Comment: @MamMam Actually this expression `1/r^2 D[r^2 D[u[r], r], r]`  is the Laplacian in spherical coordinates. So there is no any typo in my expression `oper`. Please pay attention that 4 methods give us -0.5 at `eps=0`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I confused spherical coordinates with polar ones. With a one-dimensional problem it is clear, but not quite with cylindrical coordinates. When passing from a cylindrical coordinate system to a one-dimensional one, a transition occurs to a polar system, and most likely this is the reason why the ground state is not found again in the case of a cylindrical coordinate system?

Comment: That is, I would like to get the ground state of such a system, written in a cylindrical coordinate system `H = Simplify[-1/2* Laplacian[u[r, z], {r, \[Theta], z}, "Cylindrical"] + V[r, z]*u[r, z]]` `{vals, funs} = NDEigensystem[H, u[r, z], {r, 0, rmax}, {z, -zmax, zmax}, 20, Method -> {"Eigensystem" -> "Direct"}]`. The potential is rewritten in the spherical system, but not the Laplacian, which should be written in the polar system in this case, if I understand correctly. `{-0.129444 + 0. I, -0.105166 + 0. I, -0.0701313 + 0. I...` for `rmax` and `zmax` =12

Comment: @MamMam Actually in my answer there are 4 models and one of them is 2D model in cylindrical coordinates - blue 0 markers.  As I understand, you try to test your model with `a, b` it is why you using cylindrical coordinates. But your potential depends on `r` in spherical coordinates.  Therefore we can compute the ground state in the spherical coordinates.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed explanation!

Comment: Yes, indeed, in this case we can switch to a spherical coordinate system

Comment: We actually can not influence on the Arnoldi method in any way to get the basic state for any parameter eps (through any of the options)?

Comment: @MamMam Please pay attention that model for the Slater type orbitals is the best one in this case, and your model with `a, b` is also good. But models with `NDEigensystem`  look very poor.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Yes, I realize that for this system, the approaches discussed above are best suited. But if, for example, a field is added, then such a system will have cylindrical symmetry, then most likely it is necessary to use a cylindrical coordinate system