# Issue with numerical evaluation of eigensystem

Tags: eigenvalues

I am calculating eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian numerically but I am getting avoided crossings and gap in the curves (see the output of the code) which are not correct. Please help me out to resolve this issue in the attached notebook. I tried a lot to resolve it but unsuccessful. Thanks.

```
c = 3*10^8;
m = (0.16*5.1*10^5)/(c^2);
\[HBar] = 6.6*10^-16;
v = 5*10^5;
\[Lambda] = 0.5*1.65*10^-28;
g = 8.4;
mu = 5.78*10^-5;
\[CapitalDelta] = -0.5*g*mu*B;
\[Omega]0 = (\[HBar]*B)/(m);
\[Omega]D = Sqrt[2*\[HBar]*B*v^2];
ll = Sqrt[(2*B)/(\[HBar])];
Block[{L = 100, \[CapitalGamma] = 1.3*10^-3, i, j, one, a, adag, wa, 
  qd, H, Es, list, nn, x},
 one = IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
 a = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; i - j == 1 -> Sqrt[j], {L, L}, 0.];
 adag = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; j - i == 1 -> Sqrt[i], {L, L}, 0.];
 wa = ll^3*\[Lambda]*(a . a . a + adag . adag . adag);
 qd = \[Omega]0*(adag . a);
 H[B_] = 
  ArrayFlatten[
   Normal[{{(\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd + wa, 
      I*\[Omega]D*a}, {-I*\[Omega]D*
       adag, (-\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd - wa}}]];
 list[B_?NumericQ] := Sort@Eigenvalues[H[N[B]]];
 list[B_?NumericQ, nn_] := list[B][[nn]];
 Plot[Evaluate@
   Transpose@Delete[Table[list[B, nn], {nn, 2*L}], L + 1], {B, 0, 40},
   PlotRange -> {{0, 40}, {-0.1, 0.1}}, ImageSize -> 500]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tracking Eigenvalues Through a Crossing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/165167/tracking-eigenvalues-through-a-crossing)

Comment: Thanks. But this is not answer to my question. I want to solve it with Eigensystem. Is there any option to correct this code If you know please let me know?

Comment: But in the code you provided, you use `Eigenvalues` not `Eigensystem` ...

Comment: Yes, you are right. I want the correct solution with Eigenvalues. If you can do it with Eigensystem, it will also appreciated. I tried it with both Eigenvalues and Eigensystem but all my efforts were in vain. Therefore, I posted it here.

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2941144).

Answer (score 3):

Your code has fatal error in simultaneously usage `Plot` and `Transpose`. Also code is time consuming since `list[B]` computes `2 L` times for every `B` while we need one time only. To simplifier problem we first compute one eigenvalue plot as follows

```
pl1=Block[{L = 100, \[CapitalGamma] = 1.3*10^-3, i, j, one, a, adag, wa, 
  qd, H, Es, list, nn, x}, 
 one = IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
 a = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; i - j == 1 -> Sqrt[j], {L, L}, 0.];
 adag = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; j - i == 1 -> Sqrt[i], {L, L}, 0.];
 wa = ll^3*\[Lambda]*(a . a . a + adag . adag . adag);
 qd = \[Omega]0*(adag . a);
 H[B_] = 
  ArrayFlatten[
   Normal[{{(\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd + wa, 
      I*\[Omega]D*a}, {-I*\[Omega]D*
       adag, (-\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd - wa}}]];
 list[B_?NumericQ] := Sort@Eigenvalues[H[N[B]]];
 list[B_?NumericQ, nn_] := list[B][[nn]];
 Plot[Evaluate@list[B, 2 L], {B, 0, 40}, PlotRange -> All, 
  ImageSize -> 500]]
```

Then we compute data for the last `2L-1` eigenvalues   as

```
eb = Block[{L = 100, \[CapitalGamma] = 1.3*10^-3, i, j, one, a, adag, 
     wa, qd, H, Es, list, nn, x}, 
    one = IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray, 
      WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
    a = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; i - j == 1 -> Sqrt[j], {L, L}, 0.];
    adag = 
     SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; j - i == 1 -> Sqrt[i], {L, L}, 0.];
    wa = ll^3*\[Lambda]*(a . a . a + adag . adag . adag);
    qd = \[Omega]0*(adag . a);
    H[B_] = 
     ArrayFlatten[
      Normal[{{(\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd + wa, 
         I*\[Omega]D*a}, {-I*\[Omega]D*
          adag, (-\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd - wa}}]];
    list[B_?NumericQ] := Sort@Eigenvalues[H[N[B]]];
    Table[Drop[list[B], L + 1], {B, 0, 40}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Note, that it takes 0.24 s only. Finally we show `pl1` and `eb` in one plot

```
Show[pl1, 
 ListPlot[eb // Transpose, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {0, 40}, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium]}]]
```

[image: Figure 1]
As we can see there is no any crossing or gap. Also we can check region $0\le B\le 1$

```
pl2=Block[{L = 100, \[CapitalGamma] = 1.3*10^-3, i, j, one, a, adag, wa, 
  qd, H, Es, list, nn, x}, 
 one = IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray, 
   WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
 a = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; i - j == 1 -> Sqrt[j], {L, L}, 0.];
 adag = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; j - i == 1 -> Sqrt[i], {L, L}, 0.];
 wa = ll^3*\[Lambda]*(a . a . a + adag . adag . adag);
 qd = \[Omega]0*(adag . a);
 H[B_] = 
  ArrayFlatten[
   Normal[{{(\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd + wa, 
      I*\[Omega]D*a}, {-I*\[Omega]D*
       adag, (-\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd - wa}}]];
 list[B_?NumericQ] := Sort@Eigenvalues[H[N[B]]];
 list[B_?NumericQ, nn_] := list[B][[nn]];
 Plot[Evaluate@list[B, 2 L], {B, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 500, 
  PlotRange -> {-.1, .3}]] 
vals = Block[{L = 100, \[CapitalGamma] = 1.3*10^-3, i, j, one, a, 
     adag, wa, qd, H, Es, list, nn, x}, 
    one = IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray, 
      WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
    a = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; i - j == 1 -> Sqrt[j], {L, L}, 0.];
    adag = 
     SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; j - i == 1 -> Sqrt[i], {L, L}, 0.];
    wa = ll^3*\[Lambda]*(a . a . a + adag . adag . adag);
    qd = \[Omega]0*(adag . a);
    H[B_] = 
     ArrayFlatten[
      Normal[{{(\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd + wa, 
         I*\[Omega]D*a}, {-I*\[Omega]D*
          adag, (-\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd - wa}}]];
    list[B_?NumericQ] := Sort@Eigenvalues[H[N[B]]];
    Table[Drop[list[B], L + 1], {B, 0, 1, .05}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

Visualization

```
Show[pl2, 
 ListPlot[vals // Transpose, PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium]}]]
```

[image: Figure2]

In this region also there is no crossing or gap.

**Update 1.** Nevertheless these data consist of zigzag due to Arnoldi algorithm instability. To exclude zigzag for first 100 eigenvalues, we can increase dimension of matrix up to $400\times 400$ and then take 100 eigenvalues only as follows

```
c = 3*10^8;
m = (0.16*5.1*10^5)/(c^2);
\[HBar] = 6.6*10^-16;
v = 5*10^5;
\[Lambda] = 0.5*1.65*10^-28;
g = 8.4;
mu = 5.78*10^-5;
\[CapitalDelta] = -0.5*g*mu*B;
\[Omega]0 = (\[HBar]*B)/(m);
\[Omega]D = Sqrt[2*\[HBar]*B*v^2];
ll = Sqrt[(2*B)/(\[HBar])];
eb = Block[{L = 200, \[CapitalGamma] = 1.3*10^-3, i, j, one, a, adag, 
     wa, qd, H, Es, list, nn, x}, 
    one = IdentityMatrix[L, SparseArray, 
      WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision];
    a = SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; i - j == 1 -> Sqrt[j], {L, L}, 0.];
    adag = 
     SparseArray[{j_, i_} /; j - i == 1 -> Sqrt[i], {L, L}, 0.];
    wa = ll^3*\[Lambda]*(a . a . a + adag . adag . adag);
    qd = \[Omega]0*(adag . a);
    H[B_] = 
     ArrayFlatten[
      Normal[{{(\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd + wa, 
         I*\[Omega]D*a}, {-I*\[Omega]D*
          adag, (-\[CapitalDelta] + 0.5*\[Omega]0)*one + qd - wa}}]];
    list[B_?NumericQ] := Take[Sort@Eigenvalues[H[N[B]]], 100];
    Table[list[B], {B, 0, 40, 1/4}]];
```

Visualization

```
eb1 = eb // Transpose;
nn = Length[eb1]
tt = Table[
   ListLinePlot[eb1[[i]], PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {0, 40}, 
    ColorFunction -> Hue], {i, nn}];
{Show[Take[tt, 10]], Show[Take[tt, -10]]}
```

[image: Figure 3]

Comment: @ Alex Trounev thanks. But there is still zigzag like pattern between curves if you plot by using ListLinePlot command. How can it be removed this trend?

Comment: @user199 The reason for zigzag is that you analyze very exited states computed with Arnoldi algorithm. Actually only ground state + maybe first 20 eigenvalues can be computed with high accuracy using Arnoldi, While all other are just a garbage. Also please pay attention that Arnoldi algorithm is unstable, and it is why there is shift effect discussed on   https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/286303/why-ndeigensystem-does-not-show-the-minimum-eigenvalue#286343

Comment: I have made a lot of tries to remove this zigzag trend but I could not. If you have a more specific solution for it, please share. I have no idea about it. Also, I tried to understand it by using the above link but I could not remove them again.

Comment: @user199 Tell me please, how many states beginning from the ground state do you want to analyze?

Comment: I need 100 states for analyze.

Comment: @user199 Please, see Update 1 to my answer.